# conversion of iterator in for loop

Tags: c++

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNb04.png)

The compiler says there is something wrong with the conversion of iterators in my for loops. Can someone tell me what's wrong exactly? 
For this project, I have supposed to store values into keys. I am storing the keys and values in each node and each time theres a new key, there will be a new node with its vectors of values.

```
struct node{
  int key;
  vector<int> values;
};

class key_value_sequences {
public:


    key_value_sequences() {  }
    ~key_value_sequences() {  }
    key_value_sequences(const key_value_sequences& A) {
      myList = A.myList;
      v = A.v;
    }
    key_value_sequences& operator=(const key_value_sequences& A) {
      if (this == &A) return *this;
      myList = A.myList;
      v = A.v;
      return *this;
    }
    // YOU SHOULD USE C++ CONTAINERS TO AVOID RAW POINTERS
    // IF YOU DECIDE TO USE POINTERS, MAKE SURE THAT YOU MANAGE MEMORY PROPERLY

    // IMPLEMENT ME: SHOULD RETURN SIZE OF A SEQUENCE FOR GIVEN KEY
    // IF NO SEQUENCE EXISTS FOR A GIVEN KEY RETURN -1
    int size(int key) const {
      if (find(v.begin(), v.end(), key)!=v.end()) {
        for(list<node>::iterator it = myList.begin(); it != myList.end(); it++) {
          if (it->key == key) {
            return it->values.size();
          }
      }
    }
      else return -1;
  }

    // IMPLEMENT ME: SHOULD RETURN POINTER TO A SEQUENCE FOR GIVEN KEY
    // IF NO SEQUENCE EXISTS FOR A GIVEN KEY RETURN nullptr
    const int* data(int key) const {
      if (find(v.begin(), v.end(), key)!=v.end()) {
        for(list<node>::iterator it = myList.begin(); it != myList.end(); it++) {
          if (it->key == key) {
            return it->values.data();
            break;
          }
      }
    }
      else return nullptr;
  }

    // IMPLEMENT ME: INSERT VALUE INTO A SEQUENCE IDENTIFIED BY GIVEN KEY
    void insert(int key, int value) {
      if(v.size() == 0) { //empty list
        v.push_back(key);
        node n;
        n.key = key;
        n.values.push_back(value);
        myList.push_back(n);

      }
      else if((find(v.begin(), v.end(), key)!=v.end())) { //if key exists already
        for(list<node>::iterator it = myList.begin(); it != myList.end(); it++) {
          if (it->key == key) {
            it->values.push_back(value);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      else { //if theres no existing key
        v.push_back(key);
        node n;
        n.key = key;
        n.values.push_back(value);
        myList.push_back(n);
      }
    }
private:
    vector<int> v;
    list<node> myList;
}; // class key_value_sequences
```

Comment: "The compiler says there is something wrong" And __what exactly__ did the compiler tell you?

Comment: Post a [MCVE] that reproduces your error please.

Comment: Please tell us your error

Comment: i have added a picture at the top

Comment: Why post a picture of text? Why not cut and paste the text and save the graphics overhead?

Answer (score 0):

Your size and data methods are declared const. Therefore myList is const and its begin method returns const_iterators. Change list::iterator into list::const_iterator and it should work fine.